# Буферизированный поток Java

Tags: java

Вот мой код:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;

public class ByteReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int somedata[] = {56, 230, 153, 43, 11, 37};
        FileInputStream myFile = null;
        BufferedInputStream buf = null;
        try 
        {
            myFile = new FileInputStream("место расположения");
            buf = new BufferedInputStream(myFile);
            while(true) 
            {
                //int ValueOfByte = myFile.read();
                //System.out.println(ValueOfByte);
                int byteValue = buf.read();‪‪ // 22-ая строка
                System.out.println(byteValue);
                if(byteValue == -1) 
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Невозможно прочитать файл: " + e.toString());
        }
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                buf.close();
                myFile.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Чтение файла завершено");
        }

        BufferedOutputStream bufo = null;
        FileOutputStream myFile1 = null;
        try 
        {
            myFile1 = new FileOutputStream("abc.dat");
            bufo = new BufferedOutputStream(myFile1);
            for(int i = 0; i < somedata.length; i++) 
            {
                bufo.write(somedata[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e1) 
        {
            System.out.println("Невозможно записать данные в файл: " + e1.toString());
        }
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                bufo.flush();
                bufo.close();
                myFile1.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e2) 
            {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

    at ByteReader.main(ByteReader.java:22)
```

В чем дело? Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: @Germes а в чем нужно?
Если в **byte**, то выдает следующую ошибку:
'Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас лишний символ после точки с запятой в 22й строке: U+202A - [LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm)

Comment: Два вопроса, если можно:
1. Как поставить второй символ точки с запятой?
2. Почему так могло получиться что именно в 22-ой строке возникла такая ошибка, и больше негде?

Comment: 1. Под виндой можно вводить символы по их коду (Alt-код) - зажимая Alt  и вводя код символа 2. Сложно сказать. Код не копировали ниоткуда?

Comment: Переписывал с учебника Якова Фейна.
Если честно точку с запятой с помощью зажимания Alt так и не получилось ввести

Comment: Я немного неверно написал вам первоначально (поправил ответ). Лишний символ - это не `;`, он рядом `;` и внешне невиден. Я попробовал в ввести его в c помощью Alt в Word - добавляется "пустой символ". Кстати в том же Word есть вставка символов по коду через ui: Вставка -> Символ

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вы крутой чувак)
А как вы догадались??

Comment: Моей заслуги тут немного ) IDEA указала на неверный символ после вставки вашего фрагмента кода.